# Moxy inject UseCase into Presenter

Tags: android, android-mvp, android-moxy

How can I inject UseCase into Moxy Presenter?

```
@InjectViewState
class LoginPresenter @Inject constructor() : BasePresenter<LoginView>() {

@Inject lateinit var facebookLoginBehavior: FlowBehavior<FacebookUserQuery, User, FacebookLoginUseCase>
@Inject lateinit var twitterLoginBehavior: FlowBehavior<TwitterUserQuery, User, TwitterLoginUseCase>

...
}
```

Error appears:

> Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property twitterLoginBehavior has not been initialized

But when I inject same UseCases into Activity everything works fine.

Comment: Hi, do you execute something like `component.inject(this)` within `LoginPresenter`?

Comment: @senneco Sure, init { getApplicationComponent()?.loginComponent()?.inject(this)}

Comment: Do you sure that `getApplicationComponent()` and `loginComponent()` is not `null`? It seem you don't =)